# each function on eloquent of Code igniter

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter

is there the same eloquent function of `each` on Code igniter?
same functionality of [each](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-each) of laravel?

example:

```
$collection = $collection->each(function ($item, $key) {
    if (/* some condition */) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

No, I think the closest you're going to get with CI (out of the box) is [Array helpers](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/array_helper.html).

That being said, you could just install the [Collections](https://packagist.org/packages/illuminate/collections) package with composer:

```
composer require illuminate/collections
```

If you need a version older than v8, you can use the [Tighten version](https://github.com/tighten/collect) instead.